# Notifications table design?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to create a notification system for my social network. But I'm stuck on the database design. so when a user comments on another user I want to display "X commented on your post." or when someone follows another I want to display a notification.

This is my table so far:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notifications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The part where I'm confused at is, Should I insert a record when someone follows another person? Like... Right after when someone clicks follow button? If so, What should I insert to the row?

Comment: There may be an impedance mismatch between the feature set of relational databases such as innodb and the natural graph topology of social networks. A social network is not really rectangular and the edges along which events flow are not well suited for rows in rectangles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design your database around the data. What I mean by this is:

- You have users
- You have posts
- You have comments
- You have users you are following
- You have notifications

It looks like you are trying to design your database around one use case rather than better organizing your data.

Try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
   id int not null auto_increment,
   name string not null
)

CREATE TABLE Posts(
   id int not null auto_increment,
   userID int foreign key Users(id),
   text string,
   whenPosted datetime default getDate()
)

CREATE TABLE Comments(
   id int not null auto_increment,
   userID int foreign key Users(id),
   postID int foreign key Posts(id),
   text string
)

CREATE TABLE Followers(
   userID int foreign key Users(id),
   followedUserID int foreign key Users(id)
)


CREATE TABLE Notifications(
   id int not null auto_increment,
   generated date default getDate(),
   text string //and other meta-data
   isRead bit not null default 0
)
```

---

> so when a user comments on another user I want to display "X commented on your post."

When you generate a comment you can immediately insert a notification into the Notification table (this is straightforward).

> Should I insert a record when someone follows another person? Like... Right after when someone clicks follow button? If so, What should I insert to the row?

Now, since you have a `Followers` table you can add them to that table on clicking that button.

You can then do either:

1. Check when you submit a post in the future add a new notification (and ignore all previous posts)
2. Immediately create a notification for all posts after a given time period

I recommend the first option, to me "follow" implies "follow all new content."

Comment: Thanks... I guess you're missing an `user_id` field. If there is no `user_id` field, How do you know if it's belongs to that user?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that :
Create a new table , Name it something like : Followers with a `composite primary key` and reference the foreign keys to your `'Notifications"` table
Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Follower (
  userid integer,
  Followeruserid integer,
  primary key (userid, Followeruserid)
);
```